# Automapper returns null

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've the abstract class `AbsProduct`

```
public abstract class AbsProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public abstract double Accept(IProductVisitor visitor);

}
```

and the `ProductDTO`:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My configuration is

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<AbsProduct, ProductDTO>();
    config.CreateMap<ProductDTO, AbsProduct>();
});
```

The problem is when I try to map `ProductDTO` to `AbsProduct`:

```
var product = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ProductDTO, AbsProduct>(productDTO);
```

`AutoMapper` is returning `null`, but the source(*productDTO*) isn't `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't instantiate an `abstract` class.

Try create a type that derives from `AbsProduct` and use that type instead of it.